# Forcing a category with a frequency of zero to a bar chart

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a vector of observations, and I wish to plot a bar chart in R.

The vector contains discrete values from 0 to 9. There are no observations of 6, however when I plot it, I would like 6 to appear on the x-axis, with no bar above it. I coulnd't find anywhere online guidance how to do it.

My code so far is:

```
sick = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9)
ft = data.frame(table(sick))
colnames(ft) = c('Value','Freq')
ft$Perc = round(ft$Freq / sum(ft$Freq) * 100,1)
counts = table(sick)
bp = barplot(counts, main="Sick Leave Distribution", ylab = "Frequency", xlab = "Days of Sick Leave Taken" , ylim = c(0,10), cex.names = 1, col = "blue", names.arg=gsub("\\s","\n", unique(sick)))
text(x=bp, y=counts, labels=round(counts,0), pos=3, xpd=NA)
```

The code is working fine, but I would like the value of 6 to be added to the x-axis. How can it be done in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a factor to the table function fixes this. And you'll also need to adjust `name.arg`.

```
sick = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9)
ft = data.frame(table(sick))
colnames(ft) = c('Value','Freq')
ft$Perc = round(ft$Freq / sum(ft$Freq) * 100,1)
counts = table(factor(sick,levels = c(0:9)))
bp = barplot(counts, main="Sick Leave Distribution", ylab = "Frequency", xlab = "Days of Sick Leave Taken" , ylim = c(0,10), cex.names = 1, col = "blue", names.arg=gsub("\\s","\n", c(0:9)))
text(x=bp, y=counts, labels=round(counts,0), pos=3, xpd=NA)
```